# Telebot кнопка "Назад"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я написал бота, создал меню и кнопку "назад", но эта кнопка не работает потому, что не знаю как задать ссылку на предыдущее меню.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['Сантехника'])
def handle_start(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    user_markup.row('/Назад') # <--------- Вот эта кнопка 
    user_markup.row('Раковина', 'Унитаз')
    user_markup.row('Биде')
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите коллекцию', reply_markup=user_markup)
```

Это у меня подменю. Если нажать на на команду "Раковина" то бот отправит рисунки. А вот если я хочу вернутся на предыдущее меню должен нажат на кнопку "Назад".

Так вот вопрос, как написать код или дать ссылку на предыдущее меню?

Comment: Добавте фрагмент кода, где у вас возникли затруднения.

Comment: Это у меня подменю. Если нажать на на команду "Раковина" то бот отправить рисунки. А вот если я хочу вернутся на предыдущее меню должен нажат на кнопку "НАЗАД", так вот вопрос как написать код или дать ссылку на предыдущее меню?

Comment: @bot.message_handler(commands=['Сантехника'])
def handle_start(message):

   user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
   user_markup.row('/Назад') <-------------- Вот эта кнопка 
   user_markup.row('Раковина', 'Унитаз')
   user_markup.row('Биде')
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите коллекцию', reply_markup=user_markup)

Comment: Кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/690759/edit) перенесите комментарии в вопрос.

Comment: https://groosha.gitbooks.io/telegram-bot-lessons/content/chapter11.html

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['Сантехника'])   
def handle_start(message):
   user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
   user_markup.row('/Назад') <----- Вот эта кнопка 
   user_markup.row('Раковина', 'Унитаз')
   user_markup.row('Биде')
   bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Выберите коллекцию', reply_markup=user_markup)
```

Comment: Вы действителльно хотите ответить на свой вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Тут можно добавить логическую переменную чтобы понимать в каком меню находится юзер
При входе в "сантехнка"

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['Сантехника'])   
        def handle_start(message):
                menu_plumbing = True
                #остальной код\
```

и добавить команду "назад" которая будет возвращать тебя на меню назад в зависимости от того меню в котором ты находишься

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['Назад'])   
            def handle_start(message):
                    if menu_plumbing:
                            menu_plumbing = False
                            #тут можно уже или как то так
                            handle_start('Другое меню')
                            #или просто создать и отправить новую клаву юзеру
                            user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
                            user_markup.row('Кнопка')
                            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Новая клавиатура', reply_markup=user_markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Здесь бот реагирует на текстовые сообщения от пользователя (они же являются текстом кнопок), поэтому перехватывать их нужно так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text == 'Назад':
        handle_start(message)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]